# Unable to create table from select MySQL

Tags: mysql

I can create a table on my MySQL server database with no data in as such

```
 CREATE TABLE plu_to_stock  (
 ITEM_NUMBER VARCHAR(31),
 QTY_AVAILABLE DECIMAL(18,4)
 )
```

How come I can't do as this ?

```
CREATE TABLE plu_to_stock  as select ITEM_NUMBER 
, QTY_AVAILABLE  
from item_details ,
     item_amounts 
 where item_details.item_id = item_amounts.item_id
```

I get this message 
     Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
     Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

if I ditch the as

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
```

Comment: you want `VIEW` not `TABLE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: That worked... but why doesn't MySQL like me building tables like in oracle?

Comment: Does your query give correct results? Mayby the problem is in your query.

Comment: query works fine! that's the odd thing... just throws a wobble when I use create table in front of it. I followed the instructions from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html.

If this database hasn't already been built I would be rocking along on oracle. But working with the tools I'm given :-)

View works just as well though...In fact its probably better for my design in the log run.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE tableNameDifferentFromTheOneYouUsedAbove 
ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT itD.item_id AS ITEM_NUMBER, 
                     itA.item_id AS QTY_AVAILABLE  
              FROM item_details AS itD  
                 JOIN  item_amounts AS itA
                    ON itD.item_id = itA.item_id
```

Comment: That didn't work ether.. However I have a work around I think

Comment: @TuckRollworthy What error did you get ? Also, if you post the schema of those 2 tables `item_details` and `item_amounts` it will be helpful because the syntax I gave is correct, any further error could come from what follows the `FROM` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT itD.item_id AS ITEM_NUMBER, 
                 itA.item_id AS QTY_AVAILABLE  
          into new_table
          FROM item_details AS itD  
          JOIN  item_amounts AS itA
          ON itD.item_id = itA.item_id
```

Not sure if this is the correct approach but seems to work just as well.